# I want to practice algebra&trigonometry precalculus hard problems

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, reference-request

I am Preparing for a scholarship exam, I want to practice  algebra&trigonometry or precalculus difficult problems  because the exam questions   with aren't easy. pleases suggest any book or website I'll be grateful for that

Comment: Can you get access to a school library, or a university library? Go into the stacks, go through the books, until you find one that is at your level. Then read it - or at least a few chapters from it.

Comment: Also mathematical Olympiad's and competitions generally have hard problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Aops](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Olympiad_books)
 for reference of books and problems on various topics.